# Javascript Click Button Using Class Name

Tags: javascript

I have a button that returns the following elements (shortened):

```
<button class="minus ng-star-inserted" _ngcontent-pgs-c64="" type="button">?
__ngContext__: Array(36) [ div.buttons
, {…}, 147, … ]
attributes: NamedNodeMap(3) [ _ngcontent-pgs-c64="", type="button", class="minus ng-star-inserted" ]
0: _ngcontent-pgs-c64=""
1: type="button"
2: class="minus ng-star-inserted"
"_ngcontent-pgs-c64": _ngcontent-pgs-c64=""
class: class="minus ng-star-inserted"
type: type="button"
children: HTMLCollection { length: 0 }
classList: DOMTokenList [ "minus", "ng-star-inserted" ]
className: "minus ng-star-inserted"
outerHTML: '<button _ngcontent-pgs-c64="" type="button" class="minus ng-star-inserted"></button>'
...
```

I tried this code to click the button however it does not work:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('minus ng-star-inserted')[0].click();
```

Edit (HTML):

```
<div _ngcontent-pgs-c66="" class="first-row auto-game-feature">
<div _ngcontent-pgs-c66="" class="bet-block"><app-spinner _ngcontent-pgs-c66="" 
class="spinner ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty" _nghost-pgs-c64=""><div _ngcontent-pgs-c64="" 
class="spinner big"><div _ngcontent-pgs-c64="" class="buttons"><button _ngcontent-pgs-c64="" type="button" class="minus ng-star-inserted"></button><!----></div><div _ngcontent-pgs-c64="" 
class="input"><input _ngcontent-pgs-c64="" class="font-weight-bold" type="text"></div><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-pgs-c64="" class="buttons"><button _ngcontent-pgs-c64="" type="button" 
class="plus ng-star-inserted"></button><!----></div></div></app-spinner><div _ngcontent-pgs-c66="" class="bets-opt-list"><button _ngcontent-pgs-c66="" 
class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm bet-opt ng-star-inserted"><span _ngcontent-pgs-c66=""> 10 </span></button><button _ngcontent-pgs-c66="" 
class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm bet-opt ng-star-inserted"><span _ngcontent-pgs-c66=""> 20 </span></button><button _ngcontent-pgs-c66="" 
class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm bet-opt ng-star-inserted"><span _ngcontent-pgs-c66=""> 50 </span></button><button _ngcontent-pgs-c66="" 
class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm bet-opt ng-star-inserted"><span _ngcontent-pgs-c66=""> 100 </span></button><!----></div></div><div _ngcontent-pgs-c66="" 
class="buttons-block"><button _ngcontent-pgs-c66="" class="btn btn-success bet ng-star-inserted"><span _ngcontent-pgs-c66="" 
class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center"><label _ngcontent-pgs-c66="" 
class="label text-uppercase"> Bet </label><label _ngcontent-pgs-c66="" 
class="amount"><span _ngcontent-pgs-c66="">5.00</span><span _ngcontent-pgs-c66="" 
class="currency"> ZAR</span></label></span></button><!----><!----><!----><!----></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you paste the actual HTML for the button?

Comment: What doesn't work ? The clik or the element you try to get is undefined ?

Comment: It returns: undefined

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me, I loaded up a demonstration for proof:

```js
const elem = document.getElementsByClassName('minus ng-star-inserted')[0];
elem.click();
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-pgs-c66="" class="first-row auto-game-feature">
<div _ngcontent-pgs-c66="" class="bet-block"><app-spinner _ngcontent-pgs-c66="" 
class="spinner ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty" _nghost-pgs-c64=""><div _ngcontent-pgs-c64="" 
class="spinner big"><div _ngcontent-pgs-c64="" class="buttons"><button _ngcontent-pgs-c64="" type="button" class="minus ng-star-inserted" onclick="alert('it works!')"></button><!----></div><div _ngcontent-pgs-c64="" 
class="input"><input _ngcontent-pgs-c64="" class="font-weight-bold" type="text"></div><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-pgs-c64="" class="buttons"><button _ngcontent-pgs-c64="" type="button" 
class="plus ng-star-inserted"></button>
```

If you're having an issue because of some other overlap in your non-shown HTML, I'd recommend giving the button a unique ID for easier reference.